# VB.Net WPF ListView Binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I've been trying to follow examples and other peoples questions but I can't get this list view to bind to an ObservableCollection. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Would appreciate if somebody can point out my mistake please.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Duplicate_File_Finder"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dFileList}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="File Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Path" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Path}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.vb:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class DuplicateFile
    Public Sub New(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal Path As String, ByVal Hash As String, ByVal Icon As String)
        Me.FileName = FileName
        Me.Path = Path
        Me.Hash = Hash
        Me.Icon = Icon
    End Sub

    Public Property Icon As String
    Public Property FileName As String
    Public Property Path As String
    Public Property Hash As String
End Class

Class MainWindow

    Public dFileList As New ObservableCollection(Of DuplicateFile)

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

        For i = 0 To 1
            dFileList.Add(New DuplicateFile("File " + i.ToString, "C:\File " + i.ToString, i.ToString, i.ToString))
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How are you setting your `DataContext` of `MainWindow`? You could do it 1 of 2 ways: 1) set `this.DataContext = this`, or 2) Set and `x:Name` of your `MainWindow` element and then use `ElementName=` to it, in order to use it as the context for your binding.

Comment: I wasn't :) But I've added "Me.DataContext = Me" to the MainWindow's Loaded event and now I'm getting "BindingExpression path error: 'dFileList' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow'"

Comment: Sorry, I was stuck in C# lang with the "`this`" thing! (I meant `Me`). It's because `dFileList` is a field, not a property. Try setting it to a property (like you have with properties in the `DuplicateFile` class) - `Public Property dFileList As New ObservableCollection...`.

Comment: No problem lol. That worked thank you :)

Comment: Awesome. Glad to have helped. Have posted as an answer if you'd like to check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to ensure your `dFileList` is a **property**, not a *field*, (which it currently is):

```
Public Property dFileList As New ObservableCollection(Of DuplicateFile)
```

---

You also need to tell your `Window` what to use as a `DataContext`.

You can do this in the `InitializeComponent` or `Loaded` subroutine:

```
Me.DataContext = Me
```

*Or* in your XAML, set an `x:Name` for the `Window`, such as `x:Name="mainWindow"`.

Then set the `ListView`'s `Binding` to refer to the element for the right context: `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dFileList, ElementName=mainWindow}"`.

---

Your bindings should then work perfectly :)

Hope this helps.